# mobile browser close event

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am developing Jquery mobile web application for android/iphone.
what is the closing event of mobile browser like safari/android default browser?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    alert('Leaving...');
}
```

But the event in unload:

- http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: I think for the device browser this will not work. Any option for device browser close event?